# Having a pull request conflict issue

Tags: python, git, pull-request

I am trying to merge a branch with the master branch but my conflict is hard to resolve as it says use cmd line and with the cmd line options give it doesnt resolve the issue.

Github is giving me this...

Step 1: From your project repository, bring in the changes and test.

```
git fetch origin
git checkout -b static origin/static
git merge master
```

Step 2: Merge the changes and update on GitHub.

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff static
git push origin master
```

Then when i try it i get this output

```
(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git fetch origin

(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git checkout -b static origin/static
fatal: A branch named 'static' already exists.

(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git merge master
Already up to date.

(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 2 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git merge --no-ff static
Already up to date.

(venv) C:\Users\jferguson\PycharmProjects\WebP1\DEMOPROJECT>git push origin master
To fortress-sefa.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

The conflicting files are

```
DEMOPROJECT/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-37.pyc
DEMOPROJECT/__pycache__/settings.cpython-37.pyc
DEMOPROJECT/__pycache__/urls.cpython-37.pyc
DEMOPROJECT/__pycache__/wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
```

Is there a significance in the fact it is cache files?

Comment: No, those are compiled files, you should probably add these to the `.gitignore`.

Comment: `*.pyc` files do not generally belong in VCS. Do `git -rm --cached __pycache__` then add `*.pyc` to your `.gitignore`

Comment: @DeepSpace thank you! SOunds like itll do the trick

Comment: Please add https://gitignore.io/api/python to your gitignore file.

Comment: @Joelad also note that blindly following the instructions even post-error might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I did find that... Takes a lot of care and concentration. Fun learning on the job...

Comment: @Joelad for future ref, the checkout line was to take you to a branch static based on origin/static—since it already existed, checkout static suffices. Then the merge master is to update static and resolve the conflicts there, so that completing the merge into master later is conflict-free

Comment: @D.BenKnoble i'll use that in future. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are `*.pyc` files, and the Python glossary specifies:

> Python source code is compiled into **bytecode**, the internal representation of a Python program in the CPython interpreter. The **bytecode is also cached in `.pyc` files** so that executing the same file is faster the second time (recompilation from source to bytecode can be avoided).

It is thus a by-product of the Python interpreter running your program. Usually there is no added value in storing these. In fact if the timestamp is somehow newer than the file itself, it is possible that the interpreter will use the compiled version of a module that you changed, so it is a bit "risky" to keep these in the repository.

Furthermore it will make the repository larger, since each time you change the source code of a file, and you run the interpreter, the corresponding `.pyc` will change, and thus this will create a huge amount of changes that will be stored in the repository as well. Although `git` is not particularly bad with binary files, binary files that are updated frequently have a cost in terms of diskspace.

It is better to add `*.pyc` to your `.gitignore`, and remove the files with `git rm '*.pyc'` to remove the files from your git repository.

Python projects usually have a lot of extra files that your probably want to ignore, for example files in the virtual environment. There is a GitHub repository that has [**`.gitignore`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) files for programming languages. Perhaps you want to include these in your own `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I got my whole project moved onto GitHub finally!